# Merging list of dictionaries to remove all duplicates

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, merge

I'm trying to get a simple Python code to merge a list of dictionaries into a condensed list as I have lots of duplicates atm.

From this:

```
[
    {
      "module": "RECEIPT BISCUITS",
      "product_range": "ULKER BISCUITS",
      "receipt_category": "BISCUITS"
    },
    {
      "module": "RECEIPT BISCUITS",
      "product_range": "ULKER",
      "receipt_category": "BISCUITS"
    },
    {
        "module": "RECEIPT BISCUITS",
        "product_range": "ULKER BISCUITS GOLD",
        "receipt_category": "BISCUITS GOLD"
    },
    {
        "module": "RECEIPT COFFEE",
        "product_range": "BLACK GOLD",
        "receipt_category": "BLACK GOLD"
    }
]
```

To this:

```
[
    {
      "module": "RECEIPT BISCUITS",
      "product_range": ["ULKER BISCUITS", "ULKER"],
      "receipt_category": ["BISCUITS", "BISCUITS GOLD"]
    },
    {
        "module": "RECEIPT COFFEE",
        "product_range": ["BLACK GOLD"],
        "receipt_category": ["BLACK GOLD"]
    }
]
```

Where the module is used to sort between them and the other 2 will be stored as a list even if there's only one value. This is JSON format btw.

Comment: What happened when you tried to do it?

Comment: This blog has some examples: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-merging-two-list-of-dictionaries/

Comment: @mkrieger1 honestly had no idea how to do it, I just started with Python about a week ago and getting the data to the point where it was in that first part was a miracle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collections.defaultdict` to the rescue for your data regrouping needs!

```
import collections

data = [
    {"module": "RECEIPT BISCUITS", "product_range": "ULKER BISCUITS", "receipt_category": "BISCUITS"},
    {"module": "RECEIPT BISCUITS", "product_range": "ULKER", "receipt_category": "BISCUITS"},
    {"module": "RECEIPT BISCUITS", "product_range": "ULKER BISCUITS GOLD", "receipt_category": "BISCUITS GOLD"},
    {"module": "RECEIPT COFFEE", "product_range": "BLACK GOLD", "receipt_category": "BLACK GOLD"},
]

grouped = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(list))
group_key = "module"

for datum in data:
    datum = datum.copy()  # Copy so we can .pop without consequence
    group = datum.pop(group_key)  # Get the key (`module` value)
    for key, value in datum.items():  # Loop over the rest and put them in the group
        grouped[group][key].append(value)

collated = [
    {
        group_key: group,
        **values,
    }
    for (group, values) in grouped.items()
]

print(collated)
```

prints out

```
[
  {'module': 'RECEIPT BISCUITS', 'product_range': ['ULKER BISCUITS', 'ULKER', 'ULKER BISCUITS GOLD'], 'receipt_category': ['BISCUITS', 'BISCUITS', 'BISCUITS GOLD']},
  {'module': 'RECEIPT COFFEE', 'product_range': ['BLACK GOLD'], 'receipt_category': ['BLACK GOLD']}
]
```

Note that this doesn't deduplicate the values within `product_range`, since I wasn't sure whether the order of the values is important for you, and so whether to use sets (which do not retain order).

Changing `list` to `set` and `append` to `add` will make the values unique.