# Python to iterate list of dictionary and merge keys whilst retaining values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge, duplicates

I'm trying to iterate over a list of dictionaries and merge on a duplicate key (in this case called 'id'), moving the value (of the duplicate key 'url'), from that duplicate instance, to the first (retained) instance as a list of values.

So, to go from this:

```
[{'id': ‘XYZ', 'url': ‘THIS IS A URL'}, 
{'id': ‘XYZ', 'url': ‘THIS IS A URL'},  
{'id': ‘XYZ', 'url': ‘THIS IS A URL'},  
{'id': ‘ABC', 'url': ‘THIS IS A URL'},  
{'id': ‘DEF', 'url': ‘THIS IS A URL'}]
```

To this:

```
[{'id': ‘XYZ', 'url': ‘THIS IS A URL', 'THIS IS A URL', 'THIS IS A URL'},
{'id': ‘ABC', 'url': ‘THIS IS A URL'},
{'id': ‘DEF', 'url': ‘THIS IS A URL'}]
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide the code you've tried so far.

Comment: When posting code here, you should make sure it is actually valid python. This causes a syntax error: `{'id': ‘DEF, url': ‘THIS ‘IS A URL}]}}`  It has 4 closing deleminters and one opening and has non-standard quotes. It makes is unclear specifically what you want.

Comment: Also, you should search the archive...if I understand what you want, this question is asked a lot.

Comment: Sorry Mark, have tidied that up. I have searched the archives. I could only find posts about removing duplicates, but not on how to retain the value, and in that formatting described, which is specific to this question.

Comment: Also managed to find a solution in the archives from this post which worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69580892/merging-list-of-dictionaries-to-remove-all-duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to map between ids to a list of the urls, then convert it back to your original object.

```
import collections
id_to_url = collections.defaultdict(list)

urls = [{'id': 'XYZ', 'url': 'THIS IS A URL'}, 
{'id': 'XYZ', 'url': 'THIS IS A URL'},  
{'id': 'XYZ', 'url': 'THIS IS A URL'},  
{'id': 'ABC', 'url': 'THIS IS A URL'},  
{'id': 'DEF', 'url': 'THIS IS A URL'}]

for url in urls:
    id_to_url[url['id']].append(url['url'])

urls = [{'id': key, 'url': value} for key, value in id_to_url.items()]
```

result:

```
>>> urls
[{'id': 'XYZ', 'url': ['THIS IS A URL', 'THIS IS A URL', 'THIS IS A URL']}, {'id': 'ABC', 'url': ['THIS IS A URL']}, {'id': 'DEF', 'url': ['THIS IS A URL']}]
```

Comment: Thanks so much Bharel

Comment: HI Bharel,

How would I go about retrieiving a dict object, rather than a list object, as described in your method as well as by AKX here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69580892/merging-list-of-dictionaries-to-remove-all-duplicates

Ultimately, I'm trying to end up with the following formatting;

{'id': ABC, 'fields': {'Attachments': [{'url': 'THIS IS A URL'}, {'url': 'THIS IS ANOTHER URL'}]}}
{'id': XYZ, 'fields': {'Attachments': [{'url': 'THIS IS A URL'}]}}

As you can see, after attachments it's a list of Dict's, rather than each URL being contained in a list.

Thanks.

Comment: @jemrookie `.append({"url": url["url"]})`? I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly. You can post a new question though and I'll be able to answer it :-)

Comment: Sorry @Bharel, let me try again;

So I'm currently using the method described in the previous link I sent above, though this would also apply to your method.

I'm trying to achieve a structure of; 
{'id': ABC, 'fields': {'Attachments': [{'url': 'THIS IS A URL'}, {'url': 'THIS IS ANOTHER URL'}]}}
Whereby, after 'Attachments', is a list of dictionaries.

The two methods described currently generate each URL inside square brackets i.e ('url': ['THIS IS A URL'], [ANOTHER URL])
I need the URL without being contained in square brackets..

Comment: Have you tried the .append I suggested?

Comment: Thanks Bharel, managed to figure it out in the end.